# Inserting Modify Features Clip (Discard area that intersects) into ModelBuilder in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, clip, modify-features

Does anyone know how to insert the Modify Features Clip tool into a ModelBuilder in ArcGIS Pro 3.03?

I'm wanting to cut a hole in a polygon based on another feature class, and do this for ten different cases. If I could bring in the clip discard area that intersects tool, then I could set up the links for the polygons and run the tool to create the ten holes in ten different polygons all at once.

[image: ModelBuilder screenshot with Mask Polygon feature class and input feature class]

[image: Modify features Clip. Discard area that intersects.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add the Modify Feature tool to modelbuilder, it's an editing tool meant for interactive editing. The equivalent geo-processing tool that you can using in model builder to automate processing is the [Erase](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/erase.htm) tool. Take note this is an *Advanced level licensed* tool.

Comment: With Erase it creates a new FC, is there a way to get the similar behavior without creating a new FC? The modify feature tools don't create a new FC, so wanted to automate that behavior.

Comment: To my knowledge not without coding in python and exposing it as a tool script which you could embed into a model. Or you except the limitations of erase and adjust your workflow to replace the input dataset with the output of the erase tool?